# Fedora Linux VM guest: How to change screen resolution

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, screen-resolution

I'm running Fedora Linux 16 as guest system, inside a Windows/VirtualBox host. After install the provided add-ons, only 1024x768 screen resolution displays properly; when I try to increase it, I cannot see my Gnome bottom bar... how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably more suitable to Superuser.

Comment: [SOLVED] I solve this problem following this tutorial: http://bit.ly/8LPveA

Comment: @PauloCassiano - Can you post the details of your solution as an answer please?

Comment: @voretaq7 no way, it's closed :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `xrandr` to modify screen size among other things.

Modify  `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` and add the following:

Locate:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
OLD_IFS=$IFS
```

Add:

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x768" 70.00 1024 1072 1176 1328 768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 1024x768_60.00

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768
```

... or whatever resolution your screen can handle.  More details can be found [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8595940)